# SoapUI create a template SOAP request - reuse in testcases

Tags: soapui

I am new to SoapUI. I am trying to do the following in SoapUI but don't know where to start:
1. Create a XML file with the content of a SOAP request
2. Reuse the file created in step 1 as template in other testcases

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to achieve this:

1. Create the content of the template xml into a property file as Name/Value pairs
2. In the request, use the property(s) at appropriate place using the syntax "${#PROPERTY_NAME}"
3. In the setup script, load the property file

Answer (score 0):

1. You can also store content in an `xml` file.
2. The file can be read through a `groovy script` and the content in the file can be assigned to the Test variable of the test case.
3. The custom variable can be referred as `${#TestCase#templateData}` in the `XML request`

Please remember that `templateData` should be the name of the custom variable of the test case.